# Where is the file I just created inside the Docker container to be found on the Windows host file system?

Tags: windows, docker

I'm learning Docker and this is a newbie question.

On one hand, I'd like to understand the technical underpinnings from a high-level-view so I have the right mental model for reasoning. On the other hand, I'd like to understand what options there are to access the data inside the container (file sync with -v flag?).

#### Git scenario

Let's take a Git example. Perhaps, we can draw parallels between the Git repository and the Docker image/container/filesystem.

- With Git, the files lie in the working directory:

  [image: Git working copy]
- Once I perform a `commit` operation, the file gets stored in an internal format inside the *objects* folder and is not directly accessible from the Windows Explorer

  [image: Git objects folder]
- The file can only be accessed once I've performed a `checkout` operation to get the file out of the Git repository into the working copy folder

#### Docker scenario

How does it work with Docker? Let's take another example. I just did the following:

1. `docker run -it hello-world cmd`
2. `echo "test" > myfile.txt`
3. `exit`

[image: Docker example]

#### Questions

Now the questions are:

1. Where is the `myfile.txt` stored on the host system? Can I navigate to it with Windows Explorer on the host system?
2. What do I need to back up so I have the container including the `myfile.txt` saved? For Git, I can just save the `.git` folder. (Article: [Docker backup – Easy steps to backup and restore your containers](https://bobcares.com/blog/docker-backup/))

#### What I know so far

**Location of image files**

One thing that confuses me is that I can see the files of the Docker image with the host's Windows Explorer here:

- `C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\379664351fc1b563c0dbd5d4c815d9792bd4c89c315a16792f56b6706084ca4c\Files`

  [image: Docker image with hello.txt file]

I would have expected them to be tucked away in some internal format as with Git.

Of course, only the `hello.txt` file is visible because we are looking at the base image and not our container instance.

**Location of docker files**

Next, let's go looking where the containers are located on the host's file system. The folder name suggests that the containers are stored here:

- `C:\ProgramData\Docker\containers`

  [image: Docker container folder]

However, when I open any of those folders, I don't find `myfile.txt` anywhere even though there are other files lying around:

[image: Docker container subfolder]